# Another - HTTP request is unauthorized error

Tags: wcf

Whenever I try to consume my web service through WCF, I receive this error:

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLMnProviders'.
```

I know I have Kerberos setup correctly for this environment (it's calling SharePoint 3.0 services that I use in other applications).  Integrated Windows security has been working great but this is the first time I've tried to consume it through WCF.

I've gone through this [site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/215383) many times to ensure I have the right header.  Is the above error failing because it's expecting "Negotiate" but it's receiving "Negotiate,NTLMnProviders"?  I know I can change my headers through that site but it always has 'Negotiate,NTLMnProviders' for the Kerberos header.  Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: show us your service and client config !! What binding are you using? What security settings? We can't answer something like this without this relevant info.......

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but here are some more details...

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ListsSoap">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows"/>  
          </security>          
        </binding>
        <binding name="SiteDataSoap">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://something.com/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ListsSoap"
          contract="WSS_Server.ListsSoap" name="ListsSoap">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="http://something.com/_vti_bin/SiteData.asmx"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SiteDataSoap"
          contract="WSS_Server_SiteData.SiteDataSoap" name="SiteDataSoap">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And then I'm instantiating my proxy and calling this in code...

```
proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel =
                System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = false;

// Web service call
proxy.GetWeb(...);
```